# Number of rows effected returns zero for same and invalid data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Users table

```
 Id    Name     Email 
 1     Mike     mike@gmail.com
 2     John     john@gmail.com
```

Running UPDATE query with php Mysqli

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET email=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$rowsEffected = $stmt->affected_rows;
```

Scenario1:

```
UPDATE users SET email='mike@gmail.com' WHERE id=1"
```

The above scenario returns $rowsEffected as zero as the data is same as before.

Scenario 2:

```
UPDATE users SET email='tyson@gmail.com' WHERE id=1"
```

The above scenario returns $rowsEffected as one as the data is not same as before.

Scenario 2:

```
UPDATE users SET email='eric@gmail.com' WHERE id=100"
```

The above scenario returns $rowsEffected as zero as the Id does not exists.

Here in the above scenarios, how to determine whether the update has been successful or not. How to differentiate between scenarios 1 , 2 with 3. I meant how to can we test whether an invalid update request with Id happens.

Comment: That's a fair question and luckily, mysqli has a solution, a bit awkward but works perfectly

Comment: You can look example here: https://phpize.online/?phpses=c85878f3d736675029abaddefcd54fc0&sqlses=1ef1d387c4c4659802a360d1ec8471ac&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57